# How do I automatically redirect a heroku app URL to my custom domain with Django?

Tags: python, django, redirect, heroku

I have a heroku app using django at `example.herokuapp.com`.
I also have a custom domain that points to this heroku app at `example.com`

How can I make it so that any time someone goes to `example.herokuapp.com`, it automatically redirects to my custom domain at `example.com`?

I essentially only want users to see the url `example.com` even if they type in `example.herokuapp.com`

Keep in mind that this is a django app. I could redirect every route to my custom domain, but I am wondering if there is any easier/better way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution is to just add middleware to the django app with a `process_request()` function that will be called everytime a route is requested.
I got the code from here: https://github.com/etianen/django-herokuapp/blob/master/herokuapp/middleware.py

Here is a file middelware.py that can be added:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.core.exceptions import MiddlewareNotUsed
from django.conf import settings

SITE_DOMAIN = "example.com"

class CanonicalDomainMiddleware(object):

    """Middleware that redirects to a canonical domain."""

    def __init__(self):
        if settings.DEBUG or not SITE_DOMAIN:
            raise MiddlewareNotUsed

    def process_request(self, request):
        """If the request domain is not the canonical domain, redirect."""
        hostname = request.get_host().split(":", 1)[0]
        # Don't perform redirection for testing or local development.
        if hostname in ("testserver", "localhost", "127.0.0.1"):
            return
        # Check against the site domain.
        canonical_hostname = SITE_DOMAIN.split(":", 1)[0]
        if hostname != canonical_hostname:
            if request.is_secure():
                canonical_url = "https://"
            else:
                canonical_url = "http://"
            canonical_url += SITE_DOMAIN + request.get_full_path()
            return redirect(canonical_url, permanent=True)
```

Lastly, be sure to add this class to the MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES list in the settings.py file.

Comment: I'm trying this but getting ` __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`. How should I reference this in `MIDDLEWARE` settings?

Comment: actually scratch that, this is not working for me with Django 1.11. It's simply not redirecting. Notice that I have both `MIDDLEWARE` and `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` in my settings file.

Answer (score 0):

It has been long time after [@rishubk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5092350/rishubk) 's answer and I thought it can be better if I mention corrected `CanonicalDomainMiddleware` for currently Django 3.x and 4.x versions (and maybe for future ones).

Here how I changed, you can find:

https://github.com/berkaymizrak/Resume-Django-Web-App/blob/main/resume/CanonicalDomainMiddleware.py

As I see the basic changes are init function takes 2 arguments and you must use `return self.get_response...` if you want to do nothing instead of returning None.

```py
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.core.exceptions import MiddlewareNotUsed
from django.conf import settings


class CanonicalDomainMiddleware(object):

    """Middleware that redirects to a canonical domain."""

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
        if settings.DEBUG or not settings.SITE_DOMAIN:
            raise MiddlewareNotUsed

    def __call__(self, request):
        """If the request domain is not the canonical domain, redirect."""
        hostname = request.get_host().split(":", 1)[0]
        # Don't perform redirection for testing or local development.
        if hostname in ("testserver", "localhost", "127.0.0.1"):
            return self.get_response(request)
        # Check against the site domain.
        canonical_hostname = settings.SITE_DOMAIN.split(":", 1)[0]
        if hostname == canonical_hostname:
            return self.get_response(request)
        else:
            if request.is_secure():
                canonical_url = "https://"
            else:
                canonical_url = "http://"
            canonical_url += settings.SITE_DOMAIN + request.get_full_path()
            return redirect(canonical_url, permanent=True)
```